# Function pointers compiling error

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, x86-64

While I practicing my self to study function pointers, there's error occurred like this

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_comp_employee", referenced from:
      _main in main-JEO5Je.o
  "_init_database", referenced from:
      _main in main-JEO5Je.o
  "_print_database", referenced from:
      _main in main-JEO5Je.o
  "_sort", referenced from:
      _main in main-JEO5Je.o
  "_swap_employee", referenced from:
      _main in main-JEO5Je.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

And I can not get it why it was happened. I think all of this source(below) are correct.

Here is my code. 
`employee.h` defines Employee's information and define databases and functions.

```
  1 /* file employee.h */
  2 
  3 #ifndef employee_h
  4 #define employee_h
  5 
  6 typedef struct emp_struct {
  7     char name[100];
  8     int employee_no;
  9     float salary, tax_to_date;
 10 } Employee;
 11 
 12 typedef Employee *Database[10];
 13 
 14 int comp_employee (int *database[], int i, int j);
 15 void swap_employee (int *data[], int i, int j);
 16 
 17 /* read in database (for this exercise fake it) */
 18 void init_database( Database employees, int no_employees );
 19 
 20 /* print out the database */
 21 void print_database ( Database people, int no_employees);
 22 
 23 #endif /* employee_h */
```

`Sort.h` file is define function pointers

```
  1 /* file sort.h */
  2 
  3 #ifndef sort_h
  4 #define sort_h
  5 typedef int (*comp_ptr) (int *data[], int s, int t);
  6 typedef void(*swap_ptr) (int *data[], int s, int t);
  7 
  8 void sort (int *data[], int n, comp_ptr compare, swap_ptr swap);
  9 
 10 #endif /* sort.h */
```

Finally, `main.c` combines all of its header to the program.

```
  1 #include "sort.h"
  2 #include "employee.h"
  3 
  4 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  5     const int no_employees = 10;
  6     Database people;
  7     init_database (people, no_employees);
  8     print_database(people, no_employees);
  9     sort((int**)people, no_employees, comp_employee, swap_employee);
 10     print_database(people, no_employees);
 11     return 0;
 12 }
```

First, I thought my compiler confusing between `<sort.h>` and `"sort.h"`, which is I defined. But after changed header name it also throws out same errors. Will you give me some advice and tips of function pointer for me?

Comment: Looks like a linker error.  You must not have added the object file of those functions to the linking process.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I complied **gcc -o main main.c** is there something wrong with this?

Comment: Did you link the `employee.c` and `sort.c` files too? (Answer: no — you used `gcc -o main main.c` instead of `gcc -o main main.c sort.c employee.c`.) The headers provide information about functions, but not the implementation. And headers most certainly don't mean that the program will link correctly unless you include the relevant object files (or specify the relevant source files on the command line).

Comment: @Sogo You need to compile and link with the other source files or compile main only and then link with the other object files.  The linker can't find some function defintions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No, there's no employee.c and sort.c file. This is just prototype.

Comment: @FiddlingBits since this is nothing but prototype, there's nothing more than main.c file to compile, i think. Is it make a trouble?

Comment: @Sogo You need to define the missing function definitions, at least with a stub like such: `int comp_employee (int *database[], int i, int j) {}`.

Comment: Then you can't create a runnable program until you've written the functions that are mentioned in `employee.h` and `sort.h`.  You have to provide the actual functions before you can create a runnable program. More accurately, you can't create a runnable program until you've provided a definition for every function called from `main()`, and every function called from the functions called from `main()`, and every function called from every one of the functions called from each of the functions called from `main()`, and so on.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I got it! I'll test on this!

Comment: @FiddlingBits All right! I'm now make an actual function for test! Thanks! I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have function definitions for the functions that your linker is complaining about.  Add the following lines to the bottom of `main and it'll fix your linking problem:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
}

int comp_employee (int *database[], int i, int j)
{
}

void swap_employee (int *data[], int i, int j)
{
}

void init_database( Database employees, int no_employees )
{
}

void print_database ( Database people, int no_employees)
{
}

void sort (int *data[], int n, comp_ptr compare, swap_ptr swap)
{
}
```

These are just the stubs.  You must implement them in order for the logic to work.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! I thought main just refer function's fact of existence or nonexistence, but it is wrong.

Comment: Thank you again Fiddling Bits and @JonathanLeffler ! Have a great Christmas! :)

Comment: @Sogo It would make more sense to put these definitions in a source file of there own though.  Create an employee.c and sort.c file if it makes sense to put your function definitions there.

Answer (score 1):

You had several things that made me scratch my head, but here is how I made it compile -

```
$ cat sort.h
/* file sort.h */

#include "employee.h"

#ifndef sort_h
#define sort_h
typedef int (*comp_ptr) (Database data, int s, int t);
typedef void(*swap_ptr) (Database data, int s, int t);

void sort (Database data, int n, comp_ptr compare, swap_ptr swap);

#endif /* sort.h */
$ cat employee.h 
/* file employee.h */

#ifndef employee_h
#define employee_h

typedef struct emp_struct {
    char name[100];
    int employee_no;
    float salary, tax_to_date;
} Employee;

typedef Employee *Database[10];

int comp_employee (Database database, int i, int j);
void swap_employee (Database data, int i, int j);

/* read in database (for this exercise fake it) */
void init_database( Database employees, int no_employees );

/* print out the database */
void print_database ( Database people, int no_employees);

#endif /* employee_h */ 
$ cat main.cc
#include "sort.h"
#include "employee.h"

int comp_employee (Database database, int i, int j) {}
void swap_employee (Database data, int i, int j) {}
void init_database( Database employees, int no_employees ) {}
void print_database ( Database people, int no_employees) {}
void sort (Database data, int n, comp_ptr compare, swap_ptr swap) {}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const int no_employees = 10;
    Database people;
    init_database (people, no_employees);
    print_database(people, no_employees);
    sort(people, no_employees, comp_employee, swap_employee);
    print_database(people, no_employees);
    return 0; 
}
$ gcc main.cc
$ ./a.out
$
```

Comment: Yes. All of folks in this post teaches me error comes from not defining actual function. Btw, than you for your answer again. Happy Christmas. :)